# Firefox Extension - Add Element to Body

Tags: firefox, document.write

I want to add a element to the body in my Firefox Extension per javascript.
document.write("ads");
doesn't work. - no result in the sourcecode.
I'm sure the JS is executed, because I have an alert(); on this place.
It's possible?

/edit: have to use **content**.document.write

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code to inject element into HTML:

```
document.body.appendChild
```